# Find current version AND Adobe's latest version of Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

Recently, we found that Firefox had made a change towards plugins, such that the user will be temporarily blocked from running them if they are not using the latest version. Our site requires Flash to play sound and interact with the user's webcam/microphone, so we need to do whatever we can to ensure they're not getting these warnings.

One way suggested to me is to create a small Flash control, and wait for it to tell Javascript that it's been initialized. If not (and the user is using Firefox) then they are taken to a page prompting them to update. This may work, but I worry about its reliability, and about running it on every page in our site.

Alternatively, I've been researching a way to use Javascript to detect versions, without making a Flash control. I not only need the user's current version of Flash, but also the version Firefox will expect - and I haven't found an autonomous way of doing so. I don't want an admin to have to change a small value each time Adobe releases a new version. Does anyone have any advice how I could find Flash's latest available version, or an alternate way to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm not aware of any official place that announces new releases of Flash player other than the Flash player download page on Adobe's site. You could theoretically scrape the latest version # off of that page. Also, you don't have to make a SWF file to detect their Flash Player version, you can detect that with Javascript ... SWF Object and Adobe's own default embed script (now replaced by SWF Object) do this.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the second part - I actually did find some code examples of getting the installed version, so that part's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a look at [SWFOject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and the [Express Install](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/adobes-express-install/) option which should ease upgrading considerably.

Comment: Can you describe Express Install a bit more? I clicked their "learn more about" link, but it took me to an Adobe.com error page.

Comment: A long time ago (~Flash Player 6-7 I think/2004-2005 maybe) Macromedia introduced the [Detection Kit](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/detection-kit-express-install-links.html) which was handy to  detect if a particular version of Flash Player but also the express install option. This meant you could have a script handling the version detection but this special expressinstall.swf would help with seamless upgrades on the client's machine: rather than redirecting the user to the flash player download page and hope the user would successfully **download** , **install** Flash Player ...

Comment: ...(the correct version) and especially **return to the original site** afterwards...the Express Install option would only require a confirmation from the user that they want to upgrade and keep them on the same site and upgrade in the background almost seamlessly. Long story short, try embedding with SWFObject dynamic publishing(which I think is the more flexible option) and use the ExpressInstall option with the provided expressinstall.swf and test on a computer with an older version of Flash Player than the one required.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed someone upvoting this question, so I thought that I would provide my eventual solution, which I think reduced the impact of a recent issue where Firefox blocked the **most recent** edition of Flash, pending Adobe's fix.

Basically, I went with a variation on the second paragraph in my question. It does not direct the user to a new page; instead, it opens a dialog over the current page that explains it's having issues communicating with Flash. (It does *not* specifically say "Your Flash is out of date" because this can also happen if the browser is hiding flash under a Yes/No user dialog). It also contains a small fake flash object, with the idea being that if the browser wants to display a security warning, accept prompt, etc., it can do it inside that space.

The dialog goes away on its own if said Flash control ends up making its callback to JavaScript. It also installs a variable under `sessionStorage` so we don't bother checking for it again (Flash takes enough time on some computers that you might see the dialog for a split second).